# Repeated Variable at PHP 7 Null Coalescing operator

Tags: php, null

Look at this code:

```
$this->request->data['comments']['user_id'] = 
    $this->request->data['comments']['user_id'] ?? ‘value’;
```

I want to check if some var is null and if the same var is null set the same var to ‘value’.

Hence I am repeating the same variable after the equal operator, this does not feels right.

So I feel that we need another operator like `??=` similar to `+=`:

```
$this->request->data['comments']['user_id’] ??= ‘value’.
```

So if the var is null it’s set to ‘value’ and else stays the same.

Comment: @Epodax the [null coalesce operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) was introduced to write less code for situations like this. Remark that `$var` appears 3 times in your example and only 2 times in the code posted in the question. Your suggestion pushes it in the wrong direction.

Comment: @axiac - You learn something new every day, however, why not provide this as a answer / soloution for OP? It seems like it's exactly what OP needs?

Comment: @Epodax the null coalesce operator is what the OP uses right now. She searches for a way to write even shorter code, to write the long expression from the left hand side of the assignment (`$var` in your example) only once. The operator she proposes does not (yet) exist in `PHP`.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this operator and made a pull request for PHP7. Currently it's on RFC stage and if it's accepted, it is going to be merged to PHP version 7.x.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator

Answer (score 0):

Just create a utility function for this purpose:

```
function assignIfNotSet(&$variable, $value) {
    if (!isset($variable)) {
        $variable = $value;
    }
}
```

It will assign a value to the `$variable` if and only if its value is `null` or not set.

The function makes use of [passing variables by references — see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Usage:

```
$x = "original value";
assignIfNotSet($x, "other value");
var_dump($x); // "original value"

$y = null;
assignIfNotSet($y, "other value");
var_dump($y); // "other value"

// assuming $z wasn't previously defined
assignIfNotSet($z, "other value");
var_dump($z); // "other value"
```

It also works for array items and object properties. In your case:

```
assignIfNotSet($this->request->data['comments']['user_id'], 'value');
```